# WordPress installed Manually in subdirectory then mapped to using addon domain

Tags: wordpress, dns

New here...
I manually installed WordPress in a subdirectory of my hosting, and built a website prototype.  The folks I created the prototype for, decided to go with it, so I then created an add on domain pointing to the subdirectory, and had their DNS mapped to my add on domain name.

Everything works, except, only the main page shows in the menubar as the domain name.  All others (and all links) show as my original domain / subdirectory.

Is there anyway I can get things synced up so that everything is under the add on domain name?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update the all the links within the database. I suggest using a tool to do this as a lot of the database entries are serialized so you can't do a simple find and replace.

First backup your database.

After that use this [tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

You will want to do search for `olddomain.com/directory` and replace it with `newdomain.com`

Comment: Thanks Jrod!  Fortunately, it turned out to be a bit easier.  I changed the URLs for both WordPress Address URL and Site Address URL to the domain name.  We also had to update some hard coded links, but so far so good.

Comment: @M.Rudy You can do it manually the way you have done. However using this tool will find all occurrences for you so you don't have to go through each post/page and update links to images or other pages etc.

Answer (score 0):

While it is great that the (clever) hack you did has mostly worked, you might want to do things differently taking into account the long-term stability and reliability of the site. (This might seem like a spot of bother, but like I just said, it should not only take care of your current problem but also ensure long-term stability of the site.)

Here is how I would do this:

In the first instance, do not map the add-on domain to the subdirectory of the other domain, but create a regular directory for it (if you have cPanel, that would be the default path when adding a domain).

Next, install the following plugin at the staging/demo site:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Next, generate a Duplicator package (via the plug-in's menu on wp-admin dashboad).

Once the package is generated, download the two package files (installer.php and the archive/zip file) to your PC. Next, upload these two files to the live domain where you wish to create the site. Next, open the following link in your browser:

http://{your_domain}/installer.php

and follow on-screen instructions. Your site should get created and everything should work fine. (This is a WordPress site migration plugin/method that I've been using for a long time, for all sorts of use cases - including the one of yours - with great results).